# Occur _com_error when using CreateHwndRenderTarget()

Tags: direct2d

I use Direct2D to render the animation on VS2010. But when I create over 100 animation objects (the limitation amount is variable), 
the output window shows the error message:

> "First-chance exception at 0x7607C42D in StarrySky.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: _com_error at memory location 0x001C9580."

However, the error does not interupt the program, and the animation object's seems correct.
I trace the code and find out the error message print after calling

> `hr = m_pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(renderTargetProperties,
>   D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(this->m_hWnd, size), &m_pRT);`

But the return hr is S_OK. Does anyone know the reason or the solution?

Comment: The error also occurs on VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

In Direct2D, make sure you are instantiating the device independent resources (In Constructor or something - Init_D2D() in this code example) before device dependent resources. For instance,

```
// In your header files 
ID2D1Factory* pD2DFactory; // device independent 
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* pRenderTarget;

// In the source files 
void Init_D2D() // probably in constructor
{ 
    HRESULT hr = D2D1CreateFactory(
                  D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &pD2DFactory);

}

void Create_D2D_Device_Dep() //before drawing
{
  if(pRenderTarget == NULL) //if it exists, do not create again
  {
    HRESULT hr = pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget( 
                 D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),  
                 D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(m_hWnd,    
                 D2D1::SizeU((UINT32)m_pRect.right, (UINT32)m_pRectWindow.bottom)),
                &pRenderTarget); 
   }
}
```

OnPaint() method should be something like this,

void CPlotterView::OnPaint_D2D()
{

```
HRESULT hr;

hr = Create_D2D_Device_Dep(); 
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    //pRenderTarget->SetAntialiasMode(D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_ALIASED);
    pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();

    D2D1_SIZE_F renderTargetSize = pRenderTarget->GetSize();

    pRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());  
    pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::LightYellow));

    // Drawlines or ellipses using pRenderTarget->DrawEllipse() or something

    hr = pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
}

if (hr == D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET)
{
    Free_D2D_Device_Dep();
}
else
{
    ::ValidateRect(m_hWnd, NULL);
}
```

}

**At the end, do not forget to close/release the resources, in the same order you opened.**

Comment: I already use the methods you suggested to use Direct2D but it's not solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide more code details? During debugging, what was the address of the following two variables this->m_hWnd and m_pRT? During debugging did you try debugging **after** this line "hr = m_pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(renderTargetProperties, D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(this->m_hWnd, size), &m_pRT);"